# CakePHP Console Cron Database connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cron, console

I have a Webapp which is using the CakePHP 2.x framework. The main front-end works perfectly fine but I have some cron jobs which are run form the Cake Console. When I run these cron jobs I get the following error:

"Error: Database connection “Mysql” is missing, or could not be created"

There are several similar questions on SO (but none of the given solutions works for me. I have the following DB connection setup in the Cake config file and which works for the front-end:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'xxxxx.com',
        'login' => 'xxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'database' => 'goalarc-dev',
        'prefix' => '',
        'unix_socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
    );
```

I added the 'unix_socket' key after reading a similar solution. My server is running on AWS and so I opened:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And found the socket line as follows:

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

However when I browse to 'var/run/mysqld' the folder is empty when I use the command "ls -l". This would suggest to me that somethig is mis-configured. How can I find the true and valid location of mysql.sock?

A.